# Moq verify that the same method is called with different arguments in specified order

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Here's a method I need to unit test:

```
void Do(IEnumerable<string> items, TextWriter tw){
    foreach(var item in items) { tw.WriteLine(item); }
}
```

How can I configure a mock of `TextWriter` to verify that certain arguments are passed to the same method (`WriteLine`) in a certain order ?

```
[Test]
public void Test(){
    var mock = new Mock<TextWriter>();
    mock.Setup( ??? ); //check that WriteLine is called 3 times, 
                       //with arguments "aa","bb","cc", in that order.

    Do(new[]{"aa", "bb", "cc"}, mock);
    mock.Verify();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Callback to verify passed parameter for each call:

```
[Test]
public void Test(){
    var arguments = new[]{"aa", "bb", "cc"};
    var mock = new Mock<TextWriter>();
    int index = 0;
    mock.Setup(tw => tw.WriteLine(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Callback((string s) => Assert.That(s, Is.EqualTo(arguments[index++])));

    Do(arguments, mock.Object);
    mock.Verify();
    // check all arguments where passed
    Assert.That(index, Is.EqualTo(arguments.Length));
}
```

Comment: Cool. I was trying to achieve something similar with tw.WriteLine(It.Is(s => {save result, return true})) but that doesn't compile.

Comment: Your answer isn't bullet-proof though. The `Do` method could return early, e.g. after the 1st item and the test would pass.

Comment: Well, just add `Assert.That(index, Is.EqualTo(arguments.Length))` at the end of test

Comment: FWIW I went for `mock.Verify(tw => tw.WriteLine(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Exactly(3))` but I think your approach is more straight-forward.

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu I think `Times.Exactly(3)` is also very good. Actually I forgot about `Times` parameter :)